# Updating parameters in a function being called by Octave's fsolve

Tags: octave, solver

I am working on modeling the motion of a single actuated leg in Octave. The leg has 3 points: a stationary hip (point A), a foot (point B) that moves along a known path, and a knee (point C) whose location and angle I am trying to solve for.

Using the code below I can successfully solve for the knee's XYZ position and relevant angles for a single value of the parameters `s0` and `Theta_H`.

Now I want to be able to loop through multiple `s0` and `Theta_H` values and run the solver. My problem is that I can't figure out how to pass new values for those variables into the equations function.

The reason this is tricky is that the function format necessary to use Octave's `fsolve` prevents entering inputs other than the unknowns into the function. I've tried updating a global variable as an indexer but to do that I would need to clear all workspace variables which causes other problems.

Any ideas on how to update the parameters in this function while still being able to input it into `fsolve` would be really appreciated!

The code below calls the solver:

```
global AC = 150; % length of the thigh limb
global CB = 150; % length of the shin limb
global lspan = 75; % width span of the foot touch down wrt the hip
global bob = 10; % height of the hip joint off the ground during a step

inits = [ .75; 2.35; 37; 0; 125]; % initial guesses at horizontal step position

% x(1): hip joint - guessing a 45 deg (.75 rad) angle for hip joint
% x(2): knee joint - guessing a 135 deg (2.35 rad) angle (wrt to vert) 
% x(3): X position of the knee joint - guessing middle of the leg span in mm
% x(4): Y position of the knee joint - know it is 0 mm at the horizontal step position
% x(5): Z position of the knee joint - guessing the height to be ~80% of the height of a limb 

[x, fval, info] = fsolve(@Rug_Bug_Leg, inits); % when running fsolve for the first time often have to remove the output suppress
```

The code below shows the function containing the system of equations to be solved by Octave's `fsolve` function:

```
function y = Rug_Bug_Leg(x)

global AC; 
global CB; 
global lspan; 
global bob; 

s0 = 0; % fore/aft (Y) position of the foot during the step. Trying to iterate this
Theta_H = 0; % hip angle during the step. Trying to iterate this

y = zeros(6,1); % zeros for left side of each equation

% First set of equations, Joint C wrt to Joint A
y(1) = -1*x(3)+AC*sin(x(1))*cos(Theta_H);
y(2) = -1*x(4)+AC*sin(x(1))*sin(Theta_H);
y(3) = -1*bob - x(5)+AC*cos(x(1));

% Second set of equations, Joint B wrt to Joint C
y(4) = x(3)-lspan +CB*sin(x(2))*cos(Theta_H);
y(5) = x(4) - s0 +sin(x(2))*sin(Theta_H);
y(6) = x(5) + bob + CB*cos(x(2));
end function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do that!
All you need to do is create a function that returns a function.

First have your `Rug_Bug_Leg` function take `s0` and `Theta_H` as inputs:

```
function y = Rug_Bug_Leg(x, s0, Theta_H)

% ...

endfunction
```

Then, you can write a "wrapper" function around `Rug_Bug_Leg` like this:

```
rbl = @(s0, Theta_H) @(x) Rug_Bug_Leg(x, s0, Theta_H)
```

Now, if you call `rbl` with some values `(s0,Theta_H)`, it will return a **function** that takes `x` as input and returns `Rug_Bug_Leg(x,s0,Theta_H)`.
For instance, `rbl(0,0)` returns the function:

```
@(x) Rug_Bug_Leg(x,0,0)
```

Here's a sample usage:

```
for s0=1:10
    for Theta_H=1:10
        [x, fval, info] = fsolve( rbl(s0,Theta_H), inits );
    endfor
endfor
```

Comment: Thanks @jadhachem the wrapper works great! 

For anyone else who is new to wrapper functions in Octave, this link provides some more background: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Anonymous-Functions.html